# How to escape a javascript variable in a thymeleaf attribute

Tags: javascript, spring

Currently using javascript to create a dynamic form for image url's, but I can't seem to figure out how to escape the javascript var the right way. The problem is with the th:field="*{imageUrl['+iterator+']}"

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
var info = 1;
var iterator = 0;

function add_fields() {
info++;
iterator++;

var objTo = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0]
console.log(objTo);

   var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Field'+info+' </label><div class="col-lg-9"> <input type="text" th:field="*{imageUrl['+iterator+']}" class="form-control" name="field1" /></div></div>';

 objTo.appendChild(divtest)
 }
 </script>
```

But i'll get the following error:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'+iterator+'"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

well, looks weird cause its a java error and you have javascript code.
But try to call method toString on your number.

```
var nbr = 10;
var foo = 'your text' + nbr.toString() + ' more text';
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a javascript function which makes a input form visible and putted the thymeleaf variables in the hidden input forms